# Error in creating user at the time of chef server configuration

Tags: chef-infra

I am installing chef server on AWS (centos 7/Linux) machine, i followed the following steps to install the chef server - 
https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html#standalone

I used the following command to create user -

```
chef-server-ctl user-create USER_NAME FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME EMAIL 'PASSWORD' --filename FILE_NAME
```

Note: i didn't add the original details here.

After running this command, user is not getting create and getting the following error -

> ERROR: CONFIGURATION ERROR:Specified config file /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb does not exist

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Did you run the `chef-server-ctl reconfigure` first?

Comment: Yes i run that and it successfully went. I was creating user after that step.

Answer (score 0):

uhh, after research of whole day i reconfigured this again and only thing i only increase CPU resources this time.

So i think it was just a CPU resources error. Suggestion for all - keep the machine configuration as per noted in official docs.

Thanks everyone!